# JavaScript Error: "ReferenceError: array is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cakephp

I want to make a JavaScript `array` and pass it to another page in php via post request I get an error in firebug:

> ReferenceError: array is not defined

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = new array();               // this line throws the error
    // Handle Submiting form data
    $("#btnSumbit").click(function (){

        $('#tblCriteria input[type=text]').each(
            function(){
                data[this.id] = this.value;
            }
        );
```

This code inside `cakePHP` view.

Comment: Try to move `var data = new array();`in the top on script or rename data to other name.

Comment: MDN has a good JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide. Also good: http://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so to create a new array write [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with a capital letter:

```
var data = new Array();
```

However you may always use a short version:

```
var data = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare Array above before it was used checking case sensitive name

```
 var arrayName = []; //  1
          or
 var arrayName = new Array(); //  2
```